# Undefined variable: "$global-breakpoint" wherever stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_link_tag is mentioned

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I have recently upgraded my Rails 3.2 application to Rails 5. After managing to run the application when I tried to access some pages this is the error I encountered:

```
Undefined variable: "$global-breakpoint".

Extracted source (around line #2)

<div ng-controller="navigationController">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'header_b2c', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<% current_user = nil unless defined?(current_user) %>
```

This is happening at all the places wherever I am using the `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_link_tag`. The `header_b2c` in the case above is a normal css file in the `assets/stylesheets` directory.

The same code used to work in rails 3.2. Searching for the error yields almost no result, is it something related to a config thing that I need to do in order to make the css files get interpreted as a css file instead of a sass file ? If not, what else might be the issue ?

Comment: This might be an issue from some LESS or SCSS code..please look for the same named variable or similar.

Comment: Tried searching for that variable throughout the app. It's not even there, not sure if its coming from a  gem.

Comment: may be bootstrap....not sure